# mysql sql optimization:order by not use index

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query:

```
explain SELECT m.*,u.username nickname,u.vip,u.appid 
          FROM wwj_mingxi m
     left join wwj_user u on u.id=m.uid 
         WHERE u.appid = 0
      ORDER BY m.id desc
         LIMIT 0,20
```

[image]

table m'id is primary key, why `order by m.id` doesn't use id's index?

Comment: It is not used it at least because the `user_id_ix` is used to filter joined rows, and it can only be used 1 index per table*. What is the **real** problem you're having?

Comment: this sql query use 4 seconds.and how to optimize this sql?

Comment: First thing, why is it a `LEFT JOIN` not an `INNER JOIN` there? `LEFT JOIN` makes no sense given that you have `u.appid = 0`

Comment: OK.I have edit INNER JOIN.but also use 4 seconds.When I remove ORDER BY m.id,it's so fast.

Comment: Try to create a composite `(uid, id)` index for the `wwj_mingxi` table.

Comment: thanks.I have solved it.and it just use 0.001s!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it!!
the reason is that `order by` not use index. 
just add `FORCE index(PRIMARY)`.

and my sql query is :

```
    SELECT m.*,u.username nickname,u.vip,u.appid 
       FROM wwj_mingxi m FORCE index(PRIMARY) join wwj_user u on u.id=m.uid 
       where u.appid=0 order by m.id desc LIMIT 0,20
```